# Let $A$ be a torsion abelian group. Then $A$ has no $p$-torsion iff $A \otimes \Bbb Z_{(p)} = 0$.

Tags: group-theory, commutative-algebra, prime-numbers, tensor-products, p-adic-number-theory

Let $A$ be a torsion abelian group, $p$ a prime. Then $A$ has no $p$-torsion iff $A \otimes \Bbb Z_{(p)} = 0$.

I could prove one directioin $\Rightarrow$. But how does one prove the converse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets consider the exact sequence $0\rightarrow T\rightarrow A\xrightarrow{\times p} A\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 0$, where $T$ is our $p$ torsion, and $Q$ is the quotient. Tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is exact, so we have the following exact sequence:

$0\rightarrow T\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\rightarrow A\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\xrightarrow{\times p} A\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\rightarrow Q\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\rightarrow 0$.

Since $T$ is $p$-torsion, every $n$ coprime to $p$ already acts invertibly on $T$, so this left term is just $T$. So we see that if $A\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is zero, then $T$ must be zero by exactness, giving the other direction.

Comment: So I was wondering if omit the hypothesis that $A$ is torsion to begin with. Do we get that $A \otimes \Bbb Z_{(p)}=0$ implies $A$ is torsion?

Comment: That is correct, since the property of being torsion is saying that we admit no injective maps from $\mathbb{Z}$. So if we had $A$ being nontorsion, there exists an injective map $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A$, so since tensoring is exact, this map remains injective, giving that $A\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is nonzero.